# Android app - generate a non-editable report

Tags: android, image, report

I am new to Android development and would like some advice from some more experience  developers.

The app I am developing is effectively a form for servicing products (i.e. does x work, does y work etc.. ). Once the form has been completed a "report" of some kind needs to be generated in a non-editable format! Initially I was thinking to display a confirmation page and when confirmed by the user simply screenshot the report, however I realise this is a hacky solution and would be rather limiting! So basically I would like some input on what options I have to implement such a feature! To be clear the output file MUST be non-editable... i.e. an image file or pdf!

Also FYI - the report file will be uploaded to a dropbox/a specified folder.

Comment: Images and pdf files are also editable.

Comment: What kind of input are you looking for? Output types (jpg, pdf, wwf) or programming solutions to use any of them?

Comment: Sorry - to clarify I mean non-editable as in not a .txt or .docx file that can simply be openly edited (with little hastle), and I guess  what I am really asking is  programatically what solution would you more experienced developers go for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDF files seem to be a good solution for you. I would rather create a Web Service to deliver the pdf, because some devices will be really slow creating a pdf, but if you decide to take a  client approach, take a look at:

- http://code.google.com/p/droidtext/
- http://sourceforge.net/p/itext/code/5420/tree/tags/iText_2_1_7